# Application receiving too many ANR's and Background crashes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-anr-dialog, anr

I have a production application based on Android Kotlin which supports API level 10 or higher. This applications is for EPOS machines. This has got a lot of ANR's and crashes reported in the firebase consoles on all activities and fragments. I have tried everything to remove this including bringing the leaks to 0 in profiler and removing all the unnecessary code. The memory management also seems to be working fine as running the app for 30 mins and regularly working on the application. The memory doesn't go beyond 200 MB.

This app has got multiple capabilities including payment module for connecting to card reader and taking payment. Printer for printing receipts. Cash Drawer support and multiple screen support for customers to look at their orders.

Let me know if anything from my end is needed. [image]
[image]

Comment: It would better if you would explicitly formulate a question in combination with at least the code section of one of the ANR sources. At the moment the question is too generic to be answered.

Comment: @Robert that is the thing. The logs do not show a particular class or a code piece where this is happening. It is either inside default java classes or onCreate of baseActivity. No code or method is referred.

Comment: ANR is about too heavy operations on the UI thread. Move some of the work out of the UI thread to background threads and you would be fine.

Comment: i have already taken almost 50% code on either IO threads or on default threads. But these doesn't seem to be helping. @jokuskay. Any other suggestion would be helpful.